# Progress Bar не работает. Android

Tags: android, android-fragment, progress-bar, firebase-database

У меня есть приложение с двумя активностями. Когда перехожу во вторую активность, с базы данных firebase берутся числа, на основании которых заполняются [progress bar'ы](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar), находящиеся во фрагменте. У меня проблема в том, что когда я захожу в активность, прогресс бары не заполняются, но если нажать системную кнопку назад (что вернет нас в предыдущую активность), а потом снова запустить активность, прогресс бары заполнены! Я вообще без понятия, почему так происходит. Прогресс бары заполняются в onCreateView() фрагмента, чтение объекта с базы данных происходит в onCreate() активности. При пересоздании фрагмента ничего не изменяется, из чего я сделал вывод, что проблема в загрузке с базы данных. Но почему такая проблема появляется, ведь когда я перехожу в активность с фрагментом второй раз, выполняется тот же код, что выполнялся и в первый раз!

Я искренне надеюсь на вашу поддержку, потому что я уже совсем не знаю, что делать.

---

Код метода onCreate():

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = auth.getCurrentUser();



    if (user != null) {
        // already signed in
        uid = user.getUid();
        name = user.getDisplayName();
        email = user.getEmail();
    } else {
        // not signed in
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setProviders(Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build()//,
                                // new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build()
                                // new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.TWITTER_PROVIDER).build()
                        ))
                        .build(),
                200);
    }

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    if (uid != null) {
        charRef = database.getReference("Users").child(uid).child("Character");

        charRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                    myCharacter = dataSnapshot.getValue(Runner.class);
                    SnickNameBottom = myCharacter.getNickname();
                    currentSpeed = myCharacter.getSpeed();
                    currentStr = myCharacter.getStrength();
                    currentStamina = myCharacter.getStamina();
                    currentIntuition = myCharacter.getIntuition();
                    SlevelBottom = getString(R.string.level) + myCharacter.getCurrentLevel();
                    nickNameBottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nickNameBottom);
                    levelBottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.levelBottom);
                    nickNameBottom.setText(SnickNameBottom);
                    levelBottom.setText(SlevelBottom);
                    stamFromEq = myCharacter.getStaminaFromEquipment();
                    strFromEq = myCharacter.getStrengthFromEquipment();
                    spdFromEq = myCharacter.getSpeedFromEquiment();
                    winsInARow = myCharacter.getWinsInARow();
                    wins = myCharacter.getWins();
                    defeats = myCharacter.getDefeats();
                    tournamentsTotal = myCharacter.getTournamentsTotal();
                    winsInTournaments = myCharacter.getWinsInTournaments();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value


            }
        });
    }
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new CardFrontFragment())
                .commit();
    }

}
```

Код метода onCreateView() фрагмента:

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_front, container, false);
            nickNameBottom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nickNameBottom);
            levelBottom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.levelBottom);
            progressStr = (RoundCornerProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.strengthbar);
            progressSpd = (RoundCornerProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.speedbar);
            progressStamina = (RoundCornerProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.staminabar);
            progressIntuition = (RoundCornerProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.intuitionBar);

            nickNameBottom.setText(SnickNameBottom);
            levelBottom.setText(SlevelBottom);

            statsSum = (float) currentSpeed + currentStamina + currentStr;
            progressStr.setMax(statsSum);
            progressStr.setProgress((float)currentStr);
            progressStr.setSecondaryProgress((float) strFromEq);

            progressSpd.setMax(statsSum);
            progressSpd.setProgress((float)currentSpeed);
            progressSpd.setSecondaryProgress((float)spdFromEq);

            progressStamina.setMax(statsSum);
            progressStamina.setProgress((float)currentStamina);
            progressStamina.setSecondaryProgress((float)stamFromEq);

            progressIntuition.setMax(statsSum);
            progressIntuition.setProgress((float) currentIntuition);

            TextView totalPlayed = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.total);
            totalPlayed.setText(getString(R.string.total) + " " + (wins + defeats));

            TextView winsT = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wins);
            winsT.setText(getString(R.string.wins) + " " + wins);

            TextView defeatsT = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.defeats);
            defeatsT.setText(getString(R.string.defeats) + " " + defeats);

            TextView tournamentsTotalT = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tournamentsTotal);
            tournamentsTotalT.setText(getString(R.string.tournamentsTotal) + " " + tournamentsTotal);

            TextView tournamentsWinsT = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tournamentsWins);
            tournamentsWinsT.setText(getString(R.string.tournamentsWins) + " " + winsInTournaments);

            TextView winsInARowT = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.winsInARow);
            winsInARowT.setText(getString(R.string.winsInARow) + " " + winsInARow);

            return view;
```

---

Провел эксперимент, запустил активность, выключил интернет, нажал назад и перезапустил - все заполнилось. Значит все данные уже загружены с первого раза.

[Вот видео](https://vk.com/video225137787_456239021), в котором наглядно всё показано.

Comment: если есть какие-то вопросы, задавайте, возможно я что-то нужное не сказал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас данные могут быть получены уже после вызова onCreateView фрагмента. Не совсем понимаю как у вас данные передаются из активити во фрагмент, я бы предложил загружать данные во фрагменте или как-то проинформировать его о том что данные загружены.
Например во фрагменте:

```
private boolean mViewCreated = false;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_front, container, false);
    nickNameBottom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nickNameBottom);
    levelBottom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.levelBottom);
    progressStr = (RoundCornerProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.strengthbar);
    progressSpd = (RoundCornerProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.speedbar);
    progressStamina = (RoundCornerProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.staminabar);
    progressIntuition = (RoundCornerProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.intuitionBar);

    return view;
}

public void onDataLoaded() {
    tryShowData();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mViewCreated = true;
    tryShowData();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    mViewCreated = false;
}

private void tryShowData() {
    if (!mViewCreated) {
        return;
    }
    nickNameBottom.setText(SnickNameBottom);
    levelBottom.setText(SlevelBottom);

    statsSum = (float) currentSpeed + currentStamina + currentStr;
    progressStr.setMax(statsSum);
    progressStr.setProgress((float)currentStr);
    progressStr.setSecondaryProgress((float) strFromEq);

    progressSpd.setMax(statsSum);
    progressSpd.setProgress((float)currentSpeed);
    progressSpd.setSecondaryProgress((float)spdFromEq);

    progressStamina.setMax(statsSum);
    progressStamina.setProgress((float)currentStamina);
    progressStamina.setSecondaryProgress((float)stamFromEq);

    progressIntuition.setMax(statsSum);
    progressIntuition.setProgress((float) currentIntuition);

    TextView totalPlayed = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.total);
    totalPlayed.setText(getString(R.string.total) + " " + (wins + defeats));

    TextView winsT = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wins);
    winsT.setText(getString(R.string.wins) + " " + wins);

    TextView defeatsT = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.defeats);
    defeatsT.setText(getString(R.string.defeats) + " " + defeats);

    TextView tournamentsTotalT = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tournamentsTotal);
    tournamentsTotalT.setText(getString(R.string.tournamentsTotal) + " " + tournamentsTotal);

    TextView tournamentsWinsT = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tournamentsWins);
    tournamentsWinsT.setText(getString(R.string.tournamentsWins) + " " + winsInTournaments);

    TextView winsInARowT = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.winsInARow);
    winsInARowT.setText(getString(R.string.winsInARow) + " " + winsInARow);
}
```

И в активити:

```
charRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this location is updated.
            myCharacter = dataSnapshot.getValue(Runner.class);
            SnickNameBottom = myCharacter.getNickname();
            currentSpeed = myCharacter.getSpeed();
            currentStr = myCharacter.getStrength();
            currentStamina = myCharacter.getStamina();
            currentIntuition = myCharacter.getIntuition();
            SlevelBottom = getString(R.string.level) + myCharacter.getCurrentLevel();
            nickNameBottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nickNameBottom);
            levelBottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.levelBottom);
            nickNameBottom.setText(SnickNameBottom);
            levelBottom.setText(SlevelBottom);
            stamFromEq = myCharacter.getStaminaFromEquipment();
            strFromEq = myCharacter.getStrengthFromEquipment();
            spdFromEq = myCharacter.getSpeedFromEquiment();
            winsInARow = myCharacter.getWinsInARow();
            wins = myCharacter.getWins();
            defeats = myCharacter.getDefeats();
            tournamentsTotal = myCharacter.getTournamentsTotal();
            winsInTournaments = myCharacter.getWinsInTournaments();

            Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.container);
            if (fragment != null) {
                ((CardFrontFragment)fragment).onDataLoaded();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value


    }
});
```

Comment: в tryShowData() нужно передать view фрагмента для метода view.findViewById(), использующегося внутри фрагмента. Как это сделать из активити?

Comment: Не нужно. view инициализируется в onCreateView. Соответственно levelBottom и прочие - это поляфрагмента, которые заполняются в onCreateView. Если onDataChange вызовется когда после вызова onCreateView, то будут заполнены сохраненные вью, если нет, то данные отобразятся как только вызовется onCreateView. Но я по прежнему не понимаю как вы передаете данные из активити во фрагмент. Т.е., например, currentSpeed. Где он передается во фрагмент? Или фрагмент - это вложенный класс активности? Вложенный класс фрагмента это не очень хорошо.

Comment: вложенный класс у меня, почему не хорошо?

Comment: а, не нужен view, просто перенесу в onCreateView, точно

Comment: В вашем случае вложенный класс будет работать, но, теоретически, это могло бы поломать жизненный цикл фрагмента. Я бы посоветовал избегать вложенных классов, так как они содержат неявную ссылку на экземпляр внешнего класса, если не помечены как static. А это может привести к неожиданным результатам.

Comment: вот почему IDE заставила пометить его как static)) android studio оберегает неокрепшие умы)

Comment: спасибо, ваш код работает, даю вам рейтинг и большое спасибо за помощь))

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте устанавливать данные в методе onViewCreated() фрагмента после выполнения super.onViewCreated();

Comment: не помогло, все также:(